# Binding Source of Image in an SAPUI5 Table

Tags: xml, odata, sapui5

I have an issue regarding images in an SAPUI5 table.
I am using an ODATA-Service to get the Table Data from the backend which works fine. The problem I hope to find an answer to is the following:

I want to show an Image right in each row. The image is also provided over the ODATA-Service.
E.g. I have an Entity named Part which provides some Description, so I can query it with the URL `/url/to/service/Part('id')`. The Image-URl would be `/url/to/service/Part('id')/$value`.

In the XML-View it is not a problem to bind to the description property but I have found no way to bind directly to the image source.

```
<Table items="{/PartSet}">
    <columns>
        <Column id="descriptionCol">
            <Text text="Description">
        </Column>
        <Column id="imageCol">
            <Text text="Image">
        </Column>
    </columns>
    <items>
        <ColumnListItem>
            <cells>
                <Text text="{Description}"/> <!-- Works without a problem -->
                <Image src="{$value}"/> <!-- Don't know how to correctly bin -->
            </cells>
        </ColumnListItem>
    </items>
</Table>
```

I hope it is clear what I mean.
If not feel free to ask further questions.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: I think you will have to give complete URL. As $value is not at the same level as Description. Can you try something like this :`<Image src="{/url/to/service/Part('id')/$value}"/>` ?

Comment: This one works. As a workaround I managed to display the correct images with the following approach: Binding to / and providing a custom formatter, that inserts the full url as you mentioned. I don't think it is the best way to do it but it works.